# Почему не происходит всплытие переменной?

Tags: javascript, переменные, hoisting

```js
//var a;
a;
a = 10;
console.log(a);
```

Я использую "а", по идее должно произойти всплытие - переменная должна сама объявиться, дальше переменной "а" присваивается значение 10. Почему не выводится 10?

Здесь же все работает нормально, хотя переменная не была объявлена заранее:

```js
//var foo;
function bar() { 
    foo = 10;
} 
bar();
console.log(foo);
```

Почему так? Как работает этот код?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, в нестрогом режиме есть правило о необъявленных переменных (которые становятся глобальными):

> Необъявленные переменные не существуют до тех пор, пока к ним не выполнено присваивание.

Отсюда: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Разница в вашем коде не зависит от функции. Попробуйте сравнить два кода:

```
a;
```

```js
a = 10;
```

Код без присваивания вызывает ошибку, а с присваиванием — не вызывает (не в strict mode).

Внутри функций то же самое:

```js
(function bar() { a ; })();
```

вызывает ошибку, а

```js
(function bar() { a = 10 ; })();
```

не вызывает (не в strict mode).

Comment: правило лучше как-то по другому записать, что-то вроде: при присваивании создаются (объявляются) глобальные переменные, которые не были объявлены. Необъявленные переменные потому и необъявленные, что не существуют

Answer (score 1):

Потому что всплывает объявление, а объявления ут ебя нет. Вот так нормально:

```js
a;
var a = 10;
console.log(a);
```